# PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `page_cache_directory' for ActionController::Base:Class)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

Seeing a following error in my staging environment

```
[ pid=8162 thr=3320080 file=utils.rb:176 time=2014-02-03 10:38:52.200 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `page_cache_directory' for ActionController::Base:Class) (process 8162, thread #<Thread:0x00000000655220>):
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:223:in `preload_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:181:in `block in initialize_server'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:572:in `report_app_init_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:174:in `initialize_server'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `block in spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Any clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of Phusion Passenger. The one you're using is over 2 years old. Try upgrading to 4.0.37.

Comment: Well, yeah this worked for me